# Python Scrape with requests

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

When I run this script IDLE does not continue. Usually it will give an error. Other scripts run fine so i know its not IDLE. I thought my code was correct but maybe I've missed something. This is not everything i will be scraping from the site, just wanted to see this work first than I can run through everything later.

```
import csv
import requests
import os

##HOME TEAM

req = requests.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=10%2F17%2F2017&DateTo=04%2F11%2F2018&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=Home&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=')
data = req.json()

my_data = []
pk = data['resultSets']
for item in data:
    team = item.get['rowSet']

    for item in team:
        Team_Id = item[0]
        Team_Name = item[1]
my_data.append([Team_Id, Team_Name])
headers = ["Team_Id", "Team_Name"]

with open("NBA_Home_Team.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(my_data)
f.close()

##os.system("taskkill /f /im pythonw.exe")
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not continue"?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error or No >>> after Ran. No CSV either

Comment: Maybe something in the code is wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it hangs because the server doesn't respond. It can be verified by killing the process and checking the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    req = requests.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=10%2F17%2F2017&DateTo=04%2F11%2F2018&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=Home&MeasureType=Base&Month=0
&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsCo
nference=&VsDivision=')                                             
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send                                                                                                                                           
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send                                                                                                                                           
    timeout=timeout                                                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)               
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 379, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)                              
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1121, in getresponse
    response.begin()                                            
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 438, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()               
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 394, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)                           
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize) <-- we're stucking here
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I tried to open the URL in my browser and it worked fine and I received response within a second. Then I started to tweak the request in the code to mimic a valid browser. My first idea was using a valid User-Agent and I immediately received response with the following code:

```
data = requests.get(
    'http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=10%2F17%2F2017&DateTo=04%2F11%2F2018&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=Home&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A300 Safari/602.1'},
).json()
```

Perhaps some kind of defense mechanism against bots causes the unresponsiveness without valid User-Agent.

Other notes on the code snippet:

```
for item in data:
```

Use `pk` instead of `data`.

```
team = item.get['rowSet']
```

Use `item['rowSet']` or `item.get('rowSet')` but do not mix them. `item.get` is a function so `[]` cannot be applied.

```
my_data.append([Team_Id, Team_Name])
```

The indentation should be the same as the above line

Comment: Thank you! I've never used User-Agent before. What is that exactly? I thought the code looked a little off.

Comment: User-Agent is a HTTP request header which identifies the HTTP client (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). Browsers and requests lib have different user-agents by default.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!